# Mathematical question on Mathisson-Papapetrou-Dixon equations

Tags: general-relativity

I am studying about Mathisson-Papapetrou-Dixon equations which govern the motion of a test particle around a central massive object in the pole-dipole approximation.

Given that $S_a=-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{abcd}V^bS^{cd}$ I want to prove that $S^{cd}=-\epsilon^{cdaj}S_aV_j$ where $\epsilon_{abcd}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol, $V^b$ is the four velocity of the particle and $S^{cd}$ is it's spin tensor.

Some useful relations I am about to use are $S^{cd}=-S^{dc}$, $V_aV^a=-1$ and $V_aS^{ka}=0$. The latter one is called spin supplementary condition and it is imposed in order to have a closed system of equations.

To prove the desirable result I contract $S_a$ with $\epsilon^{ajkl}$ so we have $\epsilon^{ajkl}S_a=-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{ajkl}\epsilon_{abcd}V^bS^{cd}$.

But $\epsilon^{ajkl}\epsilon_{abcd}=-\delta_b^l\delta_c^k\delta_d^j+\delta_b^k\delta_c^l\delta_d^j+\delta_b^l\delta_c^j\delta_d^k-\delta_b^j\delta_c^l\delta_d^k-\delta_b^k\delta_c^j\delta_d^l+\delta_b^j\delta_c^k\delta_d^l$.

That means that $\epsilon^{ajkl}S_a=-\frac{1}{2}(-V^lS^{kj}+V^kS^{lj}+V^lS^{jk}-V^jS^{lk}-V^kS^{jl}+V^jS^{kl})$ so $\epsilon^{ajkl}S_a=-(V^lS^{jk}+V^kS^{lj}+V^jS^{kl})$ which comes from the antisymmetry of the spin tensor.

Finally contracting with $V_j$ and using the fact that $V_aS^{ka}=0$ we get $\epsilon^{ajkl}V_jS_a=S^{kl}$ which means that $S^{kl}=\epsilon^{klaj}S_aV_j$ or even better $S^{cd}=\epsilon^{cdaj}S_aV_j$ which clearly differ with the relation I want to prove by one minus sign.

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In Minkowski signature (-,+,+,+) we have
$$
\epsilon_{0123}= - \epsilon^{0123}
$$ 
so I think your identity should read
$$
\epsilon_{abcd}\epsilon^{aijk}= -\delta^i_b\delta^j_c \delta^k_d\pm {\rm perms.}
$$
which is minus what you have have. The same is true for the (+,-,-,-) signature.

Answer (score 0):

So what you basically mean following your notation is that $\epsilon_{abcd}\epsilon^{aijk}=-$$\begin{vmatrix}
4 & \delta_b^a & \delta_c^a & \delta_d^a  \\
\delta_a^i & \delta_b^i & \delta_c^i & \delta_d^i\\
\delta_a^j & \delta_b^j & \delta_c^j & \delta_d^j \\
\delta_a^k & \delta_b^k & \delta_c^k & \delta_d^k\\
\end{vmatrix}$$ $ . Is that right?